# Making a single thread execute to completion

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked this question in an interview - not sure if it makes sense.

You have several threads of **same priority** started and running, how do you make sure that a particular thread among those is run to completion first?

You **can't use wait() and sleep()** trick on other threads..

EDIT:
Modifying the other threads is not allowed.

Comment: Is it within the rules to setpriority() to max on the thread?

Comment: @dbjohn - No. the priority can't be changed

Comment: @dbjohn Changing the priority doesn't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's deprecated and inherently unsafe (so you should never use it), but you could `suspend()` all the other threads, then `join()` on the one you want to finish first, then `resume()`.

I'm not sure if that's what they're going for.  If it is, I would doubt either their interview skills or their Java knowledge.

The "good" solutions that I can think of require at least trivially modifying the code that the threads are going to run.  Are you sure that it is off limits to modify those threads?

Comment: Yes. If I got it right, the question was formed in such a way that it is off limits to modify the threads. I was given a hint like if I can do anything from JVM's perspective.

Comment: @johnbk, Anything you can change from the "JVM perspective" requires changing or adding code.

Answer (score 6):

have one thread `join()` the other

Comment: Which would require modifying the threads you're trying to control.

Comment: It would only require changing the code of the waiting thread.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not allowed to modify the threads, you will have to suspend the waiting threads and join() on the thread that must complete first.

---

I'll leave the following (I answered before the clarification about modifying the threads was added) for completeness, but under the clarified constraints of the problem these methods would be disallowed:

Have each of the other threads call join() on the thread that should complete first. This will cause them to wait until that thread has terminated, but using considerably less CPU time than a sleep() loop would.

```
Thread first = new FirstThread();
Thread after1 = new AfterThread(first);
Thread after2 = new AfterThread(first);
```

In the run method for AfterThread:

```
first.join();
// Do the rest of this thread's code
```

You can also pass a timeout to join().

An alternative method might be to create a lock that only a particular named thread can acquire, until after that named thread has acquired and released it once.